# Tab control in C Sharp

Tags: c#

I have 3 tabsControl in the project from the 1st tab on a button_click even how can i get to tab 3.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //tab Control name is TabControl1
        //tabs ONE,TWO, THREE
         TabControl1.??
    }
```

thanks

Comment: wpf or windows forms?

Comment: you use `TabControl1.TabPages[2]` for the third one

Comment: TabControl1.TabPages[2] this is the error "  Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement"

Comment: @user1445894 you haven't told us windows forms or WPF! ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to **switch** to Tab3 when Button is pressed?

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TabControl1.SelectedIndex = 2; // switch to Tab3
    }
```

Comment: thanks mate... exactly what I want